# How can I always fit a ttk windows perfectly around columns?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I need to display tables based on queries using `ttk` from `tkinter`. 
I used `ttk` `Treeview` to create a top frame containing columns. Then a bottom frame containing three buttons. The three buttons are linked to three functions that display different information based on the queries typed.

```py
import pymysql
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

#db = pymysql.connect() I erased my info here
cursor = db.cursor()

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
tree = Treeview(frame)
tree.pack()


def stu_dep():
    for row in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(row)

    tree["columns"] = ("Name", "DOB", "DepName")
    tree.column("#0", width=100)
    tree.column("Name", width=100)
    tree.column("DOB", width=100)
    tree.column("DepName", width=110)

    tree.heading("#0", text="Panther ID")
    tree.heading("Name", text="Name")
    tree.heading("DOB", text="Birth year")
    tree.heading("DepName", text="Department Name")

    stu_dep_info_quer = "SELECT Student.Panther_ID, Student.Name, Student.DOB, Department.Name FROM Student, Department WHERE Student.Department_ID = Department.Department_ID"
    cursor.execute(stu_dep_info_quer)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for i in range(0, len(result)):
        tree.insert("", i, text=str(result[i][0]), values=(str(result[i][1]), str(result[i][2]), str(result[i][3]) ))


def inst_info():
    for row in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(row)

    tree["columns"] = ("Name", "Dep_ID")
    tree.column("#0", width=100)
    tree.column("Name", width=100)
    tree.column("Dep_ID", width=100)

    tree.heading("#0", text="Instructor_ID")
    tree.heading("Name", text="Name")
    tree.heading("Dep_ID", text="Department_ID")

    inst_info_quer = "SELECT * FROM Instructor"
    cursor.execute(inst_info_quer)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for i in range(0, len(result)):
        tree.insert("", i, text=str(result[i][0]), values=(str(result[i][1]), str(result[i][2])))


def stu_info():
    for row in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(row)

    tree["columns"] = ("Name", "DOB")
    tree.column("#0", width=100)
    tree.column("Name", width=100)
    tree.column("DOB", width=100)

    tree.heading("#0", text="Panther ID")
    tree.heading("Name", text="Name")
    tree.heading("DOB", text="Birth year")

    stu_info_quer = "SELECT * FROM Student"
    cursor.execute(stu_info_quer)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for i in range(0, len(result)):
        tree.insert("", i, text=str(result[i][0]), values=(str(result[i][1]), str(result[i][2])))


bFrame = Frame(root)
bFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)

stu_dep_button = Button(bFrame, text = "Student_Department", command = stu_dep)
stu_dep_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

instructor_button = Button(bFrame, text = "Instructor_Info", command = inst_info)
instructor_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

student_button = Button(bFrame, text = "Student_Info", command = stu_info)
student_button.grid(row = 0, column = 2)


stu_info()

root.mainloop()
```

The following screenshot shows the layout before clicking any buttons. The window initially fits well around the columns. The `stu_info` function is called at the end of the program and so displays without clicking any buttons at first.

[image: Works]

But after clicking the any of the buttons, the screen does not fit perfectly around the columns anymore:

[image: Broken]

After clicking some buttons and coming back student info there is now an empty space to the right.

*Q*: How can I always fit a ttk windows perfectly around columns?

Comment: Read about additional parameters using [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). Hint, give your `bFrame` another `background='red'` to see what you get.